# How rails sets ids for db entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

If you create say 5 `User` records then destroy them all.  The next `User` entry in the database that's created will have an `id` of 6.  How does rails know to give this new row an `id` of `6` and not `1`?  I ran into this issue because I was trying to "guess" what the next id for a `User` record would be but ran into trouble with the above scenario.  I'm currently using postgresql but I don't believe this functionality would be database dependent?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Don't try to guess, your guess will be wrong sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is database dependent. When you insert, most databases returns the id for the inserted row. In PostgreSQL, you have what you call a "sequence" that keeps the current/next id number (not sure which). Other databases may vary.

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L726

This is where it finds the current sequence: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L1513

Comment: Thanks pedro, is there any way to access this sequence to "guess" what the next id would be?